# put logic in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query where I I gather data from cars and fuelcards. In general what I do is for a given timeframe I collect all cars along with their mileage. So a possible result would be:

[image]

What I now need to do is check that the mileage for date 1 is smaller then the mileage for date 2. According to that I'd put a yes or no in a new column that keeps track if the data is valid.

Is this possible in SQL?

EDIT:

here is the SELECT code. There is more code above it to create the things like 'CarList' but I don't think that those are important.

```
    SELECT 
    CAR.beginmonth
,   CAR.endmonth
--, CAR.X_AXIS
--,   CAR.X_AXIS_2
,   CAR.CarID 
--, AL.AllocationName
--, CAR.AllocationID
--, CAR.StartDate
--, CAR.FinalEndDate
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Nature
,   CAR.BuiltYear
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   fuelcardrefill.Kilometer
,   fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelType
,   fuelcardrefill.Date

From    CarList AS CAR inner join
        dbo.eMK_CarFuelCard as carfuelcard On CAR.CarID = carfuelcard.CarID inner join
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard as fuelcard on carfuelcard.FuelCardID = fuelcard.ID inner join 
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard_Refill as fuelcardrefill on fuelcard.ID = fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelCard

        LEFT Join 
        AllocationList as AL on CAR.AllocationID = AL.CostAllocationID

Where (CAR.AllocationID = @AllocationID) OR (@AllocationID IS NULL) AND 
      (fuelcardrefill.Date > beginmonth and fuelcardrefill.Date < endmonth)

UNION

SELECT 
    AL.MonthDate as beginmonth
,   AL.endmonth
--, AL.X_AXIS
--,   AL.X_AXIS_2
,   NULL as CarID 
--, AL.AllocationName
--, AL.CostAllocationID
--, NULL as StartDate
--, NULL
,   'N' as ValidData
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL

From    AllocationCrossList as AL
--Where (ISNULL(AL.CostAllocationID,NULL) = ISNULL(@AllocationID,NULL) ) 
order by beginmonth, CarID, Date
```

Comment: Would there only ever be date1 and date2 or could this increase?

Comment: If you post the code you have you may get better answers

Comment: I know but the code is pretty large with a lot of joins. And @Matt there could be more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give you complete answer, because you haven't specified what your data model is and where the mileage comes from. So, I will try to give simplified answer here.

Say you have table CarData containing your provided sample data:

[image]

Then you can write something like:

```
SELECT
    CD1.*,
    --data is not valid if we can find older record with greater mileage on the same car
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            CarData AS CD2
        WHERE
            CD2.CarId = CD1.CarId AND -- same car
            CD2.[Date] < CD1.[Date] -- older date
            CD2.Mileage > CD1.Mileage -- greater mileage
    ) 
    THEN 'N' 
    ELSE 'Y' 
    END AS IsValidMileage
FROM
    CarData AS CD1
```

You can do the same thing with self join as mentioned in comments, but I think this is approach is more readable.

Comment: If this method helped, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just checked it. It helped me on the right track thanks again!